# Question on Turaev's paper about axioms for topological quantum field theory

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

I am currently reading Turaev's paper [*Axioms for topological quantum field theory*](http://archive.numdam.org/article/AFST_1994_6_3_1_135_0.pdf).

In couple of place, there  is a paraphrase "...  is natural with respect to $\mathfrak{U}$-homeomorphism" and I don't really understand  what does it mean. One is in the definition of self-dual modular functor.

It says system of bilinear pairing is natural with respect to $\mathfrak{U}$-homeomorphism and the other is in the definition of cobordism. It says gluing is natural with respect to $\mathfrak{U}$-homeomorphism.  It seem like that paraphrase is something I should get used to before jumping into Turaev's papers.

If so, a book suggestion would be very helpful. If not, can someone explain what Turaev means by the paraphrase.

Comment: There's a category of such homeomorphisms. Do you know what a natural transformation is?

Comment: I know what natural transformation but i don't really know how to see any entitiy as a functor in that context.